# Making object move once on button hold

Tags: c#, monogame

I am trying to get a cube that moves 100px in the direction it is pressed. But if the key is held down it still only moves once until the key has been release and pressed again.

```
         if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            mx += 100;

        }
```

Comment: Sorry, I am using monogame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_flag) to achieve this.

Define `bool flag` somewhere (I don't know if you can use local variable and should use a field, this depends on how your main loop looks like) and then:

```
if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
{
    if(!flag)
    {
        mx += 100;
        flag = true; // set when changing value
    }
}
else
    flag = false; // reset when button is not down
```

This will increment `mx` once. To increment it again the button has to be released.